# Java, Swing and Xubuntu, JFrames not correct

Tags: java, swing, ubuntu

I'm completely new to Linux and have been trying to get my (Windows built) Java Swing projects to work correctly on XUbuntu on a separate machine from executable jar files I built.

I've reduced the problem to a minimum amount of code

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.*;

public class JFrameTest extends JFrame {

    public JFrameTest(String title) {
        super(title);
        JLabel lab = new JLabel("Label");
        this.getContentPane().add(lab);
        this.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        JFrameTest frame = new JFrameTest("Title");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

}
```

On Windows I see:

[image: Windows o/p]

In Xubuntu I just see a grey box and the label, not the Title or close icons etc. I also have to kill (-9) the jvm after I've ctrl zedded from the command line. I launched it with java -jar filename.jar

My Linux machine is running Xubuntu 11. I've installed the sun Java 6_24 JRE. I Googled for this and found something similar relating to Compziz(?) but this was allegedly fixed a while back. I'm a bit stuck now. I have got one Swing app that works OK in that it responds to buttons OK but still doesn't show the Title etc. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't use Xubuntu, but the general rule is that any code that updates a GUI should be executed on the Event Dispatch Thread. See the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html).

The examples from the Swing tutorial all use a format like this:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class SSCCE extends JPanel
{
    public SSCCE()
    {
        add( new JLabel("Label") );
    }

    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SSCCE");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add( new SSCCE() );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try that in a minute.

Comment: Perfect solution, it only ran in Windows by luck I guess. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Suggestion: Start the GUI on the EDT.  Vis.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.*;

public class JFrameTest extends JFrame {

    public JFrameTest(String title) {
        super(title);
        JLabel lab = new JLabel("Label");
        this.getContentPane().add(lab);
        this.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // Costruct & show the GUI on the EDT
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
                        UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (Throwable e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                JFrameTest frame = new JFrameTest("Title");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

For more information see [Concurrency in Swing](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/).